# EXTJS How to use JSon Reader without proxy

Tags: json, extjs

Below is the code where I try to load some records using JSon Reader in the store.
I am unable to see this on the Grid.
Can you please point me out what am I missing as I don't want to use proxy/url for JSon.

```
var itemsPerPage = 10;
Ext.Loader.setConfig({enabled: true});
Ext.require([
    'Ext.grid.*',
    'Ext.data.*',
    'Ext.util.*',
    'Ext.toolbar.Paging'
]);

Ext.define('Assemble', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: [
       {name: 'lot_no', type: "string"}
    ],
    idProperty: 'lot_no'
});

Ext.onReady(function() {
    Ext.QuickTips.init();

    var jsonString = '{"result":[{"lot_no":"MT6261"},{"lot_no":"MT6262"},{"lot_no":"MT6263"}]}';

    // create the data store
    var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
        pageSize: itemsPerPage,
        proxy:{
            type: 'ajax',
            reader: {
                type: 'json',
                root: 'result',
                model: Assemble
            }
        }
    });
    store.loadData(Ext.decode(jsonString)); 



    console.log(store);

    var pagingToolbar = Ext.create('Ext.PagingToolbar',{
        pageSize: itemsPerPage,
        store: store,
        displayInfo: true,
        displayMsg: ' {0}-{1}，{2}',
        emptyMsg: "empty."
    });

    // create the Grid
    var grid = Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
        store: store,
        disableSelection: true,
        loadMask: true,
        columns: [
            {
                text     : 'LOT_NO',
                flex     : 1,
                sortable : true,
                dataIndex: 'lot_no'
            }
        ],
     bbar : pagingToolbar,
     renderTo: 'grid',
     viewConfig: {
         stripeRows: true,
         enableTextSelection: true
     }
    });

    store.loadPage(1);
});
```

Comment: can you modify your JsonString??

Comment: model has to be out of your proxy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Proxy has to use with url. So, you can't use the proxy like that. I removed the proxy, put the model in store and you have to load objects into store, but in your case contained rootProperty('result', I only get the main objects or you can remove the 'result' from the jsonString). Then, it worked. Chck this fiddle:

https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/11or

```
var jsonString = '{"result":[{"lot_no":"MT6261"},{"lot_no":"MT6262"},{"lot_no":"MT6263"}]}';

// create the data store
var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    pageSize: itemsPerPage,
    model: 'Assemble'
});
store.loadData(Ext.decode(jsonString).result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you even using a reader? Your data is local so just decode the string and pass in what you want:

https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/11qc

Also, your data is local so no need for a paging toolbar. In Ext JS 5+ the grid will use the buffered renderer (if the grid has a defined size from height/width configs or from a parent layout) so loading all the data into the store will not affect performance (other than creating the records). The grid will only render what is viewable plus a few on either side.